# How do I profile an embedded jetty container?

Tags: java, maven-2, profiling, maven-cargo

As part of my build, we use cargo-maven2-plugin to launch a jetty container with our app.  Intermittently, we get the result "Failed to start the Jetty 6.x Embedded container."  We're bumping up against the default 120 second timeout.

We're using a Sun 1.6.0_07 JVM, so I thought that [hprof](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/HPROF.html) might be able to help.

As a sanity test, I started with

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=%MAVEN_OPTS% -agentlib:hprof=cpu=samples,interval=20,depth=3,file=hprof.out
```

and then ran

```
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true install
```

(Cargo is configured to run during the pre-integration-test and post-integration-test goals)

This appears to be what I want - I see the messages for starting and stopping the container, and messages that the tests are being skipped.  After maven outputs the build summary, I see the message "Dumping CPI usage by sampling running threads ... done."  The hprof.out file is written, it has the kind of sample data I want.

Of course, this is a sampling of maven itself, which isn't useful.

**How do I get that same sampling information for my web app?**

My initial thought was to use the [cargo.jvmargs](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Configuration+properties) property

```
<cargo.jvmargs>-agentlib:hprof=cpu=samples,interval=20,depth=3,file=hprof.out</cargo.jvmargs>
```

, but (a) when I do this (removing the profiling arguments from MAVEN_OPTS), I can't find a resulting hprof.out file and (b) a second look at the documentation suggests that maybe those are only used for the start/stop of the container, and not the container itself?